# What are the steps to sign a Outlook Add-in (VSTO) without using Click Once

Tags: outlook, vsto, code-signing

I have a visual studio 2015 project that builds a Outlook Add-In.

I don't want to use click once. I wrote my own installer that properly installs the Add-In. It runs fine except for the warning about it not being signed when loaded into outlook.

My question is I have no idea how to sign the addin. I bought a code signing certificate from godaddy but I don't know what tools to use or what files need to be signed.

Specifics would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: To see if my cert is ok I enabled ClickOnce and imported the .pfx file. I get the following error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(264,9): error MSB3482: An error occurred while signing: Invalid provider type specified.

I got this from GoDadddy. The key is 2048 length. SHA-2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **SignTool.exe** utility. Sign Tool is a command-line tool that digitally signs files, verifies signatures in files, and time-stamps files.
This tool is automatically installed with Visual Studio. To run the tool, use the Developer Command Prompt (or the Visual Studio Command Prompt in Windows 7). For more information, see [Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx).

The following command digitally signs a file by using a certificate stored in a password-protected PFX file.

```
  signtool sign /f MyCert.pfx /p MyPassword MyFile.exe
```

Finally, you may find the [Code Signing – It’s Cheaper And Easier Than You Thought](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins/code-signing-it-s-cheaper-and-easier-than-you-thought) article helpful.

Comment: Outlook addins have a .vsto manifest file that I believe needs to be signed. I tried using SignTool but it says that the file type is not supported. I have tried to use mage as well and I get the same error the Visual Studio gives about Invalid provider type specified

Comment: See [Signing and re-signing manifests in ClickOnce](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsto/2009/04/29/signing-and-re-signing-manifests-in-clickonce-saurabh-bhatia/).

Comment: Thank you that seems to be the right information but when I try and run mage update I get the following error:

Unable to open certificate mycert.pfx":
Invalid provider type specified.

I am using a godaddy code signing cert. Any ideas why the error is happening or does someone have proven success with another cert provider?

Comment: I now got the signing to work - I had use Legacy creating the CSR for the certificate

But when I follow the instructions in @Eugene's suggestion something weird happens. When I use mage to sign the vsto file it actually changes the publisher name to the product name. Outlook then still does not recognize the publisher - any ideas why it would be doing this?

Comment: Figured it out - needed the -Publisher arg when updating the.vsto manifest

Big Thanks Eugene